# Pyinstaller & Keyboard

Tags: python, keyboard, pyinstaller

I'm stuck on a problem. I'm exporting code to .exe with pyinstaller. Code includes tkinter, PIL and **keyboard** modules.
Software runs perfectly on my PC with Python, whereas on the one without Python it crashes whenever I use something linked to **keyboard**.

Therefore, I concluded that **keyboard** module wasn't included properly when "converting" to .exe.

I've tried including it with adding *--hidden-import=keyboard* in the script, but it also doesn't seem to work.

Have You got any idea, how to possibly solve this and include that module into output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by changing application logic and hotkey management system. After a rigorous research, I came to a conclusion that this cannot be done in other way.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem my Solution was to use the -p [Path] argument:

pyinstaller Proc.py -p "C:\Users\New\Desktop\Project\virtualenv\Lib\site-packages"

in the "Lib\site-packages" was the Keyboard module installation.